# Keras Convolutional NN Input Shape

Tags: python, pandas, networking, keras

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below:

[image: :]

I want to give this into a Keras convolutional neural network as an input, however, the shape is given as `(20,4)`. To give it as a Keras input, its shape must be (n_samples, 4, 4, 1). How can I reshape it into this? Is it possible to set the major axis as the index?

This was created from a flattened pandas.Panel, if there is an easier conversion possible.

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: Why should it be (n_samples, 4, 4, 1). Can you show your code?

Comment: I think you can use keras build in [reshape](https://keras.io/layers/core/#reshape) layer.

Comment: @Dark, see https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/. I used 1 because the individual matrix entries are 1D. I think RGB pictures would have that as 3.

Comment: @adityathakkar, does not work because my input and output array are different dimensions.